# How to count duplicates based on a property in a list of objects with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items

- John ID
- Matt ID
- John ID
- Scott ID
- Matt ID
- John ID
- Lucas ID

I want to shove them back into a list like so which also means I want to sort by the highest number of duplicates.

- John ID 3
- Matt ID 2
- Scott ID 1
- Lucas ID 1

Let me know how I can do this with LINQ and C#.

Thanks All

**EDIT 2 Showing Code:**

```
    List<game> inventory = new List<game>();
    drinkingforDataContext db = new drinkingforDataContext();
    foreach (string item in tbTitle.Text.Split(' '))
    {

        List<game> getItems = (from dfg in db.drinkingfor_Games
                               where dfg.game_Name.Contains(tbTitle.Text)
                               select new game
                               {
                                   gameName = dfg.game_Name,
                                   gameID = Boomers.Utilities.Guids.Encoder.EncodeURLs(dfg.uid)
                               }).ToList<game>();

        for (int i = 0; i < getItems.Count(); i++)
        {
            inventory.Add(getItems[i]);
        }
    }

    var items = (from xx in inventory
                 group xx by xx into g
                 let count = g.Count()
                 orderby count descending
                 select new
                    {
                        Count = count,
                        gameName = g.Key.gameName,
                        gameID = g.Key.gameID
                    });

    lvRelatedGames.DataSource = items;
    lvRelatedGames.DataBind();
```

This query displays these results:

- 1 hello world times
- 1 hello world times
- 1 Hello World.
- 1 hello world times
- 1 hello world times
- 1 hello world times
- 1 Hello World.
- 1 hello world times

It gives me the count and name, but it doesn't give me the ID of the game....

It should display:

- 6 hello world times   234234
- 2 Hello World.  23432432

Comment: given your results it is obvious that program treats all of your items as distinct - as I said, you need to implement custom comparer, otherwise it is not possible to select distinct values

Comment: Yeah, that's the crucial part. I don't understand why people keep adding answers based on primitive values.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use "group by" + "orderby". See [LINQ 101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) for details

```
var list = new List<string> {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"};
var q = from x in list
        group x by x into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new {Value = g.Key, Count = count};
foreach (var x in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count);
}
```

**In response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq#454652) (now deleted):**

If you have a list of some custom objects then you need to use [custom comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#comparer) or group by specific property.

Also query can't display result. Show us complete code to get a better help.

**Based on your latest update:**

You have this line of code:

```
group xx by xx into g
```

Since xx is a custom object system doesn't know how to compare one item against another.
As I already wrote, you need to guide compiler and provide some property that will be used in objects comparison or provide custom comparer. Here is an example:

Note that I use **Foo.Name** as a key - i.e. objects will be grouped based on value of **Name** property.

There is one catch - you treat 2 objects to be duplicate based on their names, but what about Id ? In my example I just take Id of the first object in a group. If your objects have different Ids it can be a problem.

```
//Using extension methods
var q = list.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => new {Count = x.Count(), 
                              Name = x.Key, 
                              ID = x.First().ID})
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

//Using LINQ
var q = from x in list
        group x by x.Name into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new {Name = g.Key, Count = count, ID = g.First().ID};

foreach (var x in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + x.Count + " Name: " + x.Name + " ID: " + x.ID);
}
```

Comment: Done, You can now get a glimpse of what im looking at.

Comment: select new {Name = g.Key, Count = count, ID = g.First().ID};

This was the line that made it work.  Thanks Aku.  Its the .First.ID part that made it work.  Ur Brilliant...

Comment: Thanks for the `x.First().ID` thing

Answer (score 64):

Slightly shorter version using methods chain:

```
var list = new List<string> {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"};
var q = list.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(g => new {Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count);

foreach (var x in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count);
}
```

Comment: Simplicity with expertise.

Comment: Using primitive values make it a completely different case.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do Dictionary:

```
 var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b" };
 var result = list.GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(y=>y.Key, y=>y.Count())
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Value);

 foreach (var x in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Key + " Count: " + x.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Using primitive values make it a completely different case.

Answer (score 8):

The other solutions use `GroupBy`. `GroupBy` is slow (it holds all the elements in memory) so I wrote my own method `CountBy`:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey,int> CountBy<TSource,TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector)
{
    var countsByKey = new Dictionary<TKey,int>();
    foreach(var x in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(x);
        if (!countsByKey.ContainsKey(key))
            countsByKey[key] = 0;
        countsByKey[key] += 1;
    }
    return countsByKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not to post an new answer! Nowadays, i think you can do just something like...
`var duplicatesCount = listVariable.Count(o => o.Equals(listElement));`
then just add each element with duplicateCount at new list, with `!listVariable.Contains(elem)` duplicate blocker

Comment: Great idea posting up to date information. However "I think"? Shouldn't you be sure before posting?

Comment: Again ignores the fact that different object instances never "equal" one another, even if their values are identical. Also, what is "nowadays" about this? And how would this work with the code in the question?

Answer (score -1):

another solution

```
public static void Main()
{
        var list = new List<string> {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"};
        list.GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count()} )
            .Where(x => x.Count > 1).ToList()
            .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Value: {x.Value} Count: {x.Count}"));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. With primitive values it's easy and the code in the question would have worked already. Sadly, many answers here disregard that.

Comment: what good is the additional  `Where` ? how do you expect any group existing with `Count <= 0` ...? where should such a group come from?

Comment: @derHugo it's `Count > 1` not `Count > 0` means return only the items that appear more than one time in the grouping, hence the `c` won't be part of the result as it only appears one time which is not a duplicate

Comment: @HosamRehani ah I see makes sense

Answer (score -2):

**Here is the complete programme please check this**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> li = new List<string>();
    li.Add("Ram");
    li.Add("shyam");
    li.Add("Ram");
    li.Add("Kumar");
    li.Add("Kumar");

    var x = from obj in li group obj by obj into g select new { Name = g.Key, Duplicatecount = g.Count() };
    foreach(var m in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Name + "--" + m.Duplicatecount);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Using primitive values make it a completely different case.

Answer (score -2):

```
**Here is the complete program without using any LINQ or nested Loops**

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
            int[] result = {0,2,1,0,3,2,1};
            var arrayValue = new List<int>();
            foreach(var x in result){
                if(!arrayValue.Contains(x)){
                    arrayValue.Add(x);
                    var countVal = findArrayCount(x);
                    listItems.Add("value :" + x  + "Count:" + countVal);
                }
            }
            listItems.ForEach(li => Console.WriteLine(li));
        }

        public static int findArrayCount(int x) {
          int[] result = {0,2,1,0,3,2,1};
          int countval = 0;
          foreach (var val in result)
          {
            if(val.Equals(x)){ countval+=1;}
          }
          return countval;
        }
}
    
    OutPut:
    value :0 Count:2
    value :2 Count:2
    value :1 Count:2
    value :3 Count:1
```

Comment: `findArrayCount` is a nested loop. Why is the `result` variable repeated? Now it only works for that array. And this is yet another answer based on primitive values, please read comments before answering question!