# LINQ: Howto get person count by personid

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find the person who has the maximum items in a list like this:

```
class Person
{
   var personid;
   var personname;
   var blah;
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

Sample list

```
1 John
1 John
1 John
2 Smith
1 John
```

Sample result

```
1 3   (id, count)
```

Sample bonus result -with Top N clause

```
1 3
2 1
```

Plus; Top N clause would be nice if any/built-in. I would like to learn both versions; with or without Top clause.

Comment: Maximum items of what? Is `blah` a collection?

Comment: Poorly worded question sorry -1.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Thanks for formatting, it looks awesome. I wrote in a hurry, sorry.

Comment: @NimeCloud: Np. Btw, you can use Ctrl-K to indent selected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Max :**

```
var biggestGrpOfPeopleHavingSamePersonId = 
people.GroupBy(x => x.personid).Max(x => x.Count());
```

**Top :**

```
var top3peopleGroups = 
people.GroupBy(x => x.personid).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Take(3);
```

**EDIT :**

The first query returns an element of type `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>` where `TKey` is of the same type of `personid` and `TValue` is of type `Person`. The second query returns an `IEnumerable<>` of objects like that.

So, for example in the second case you can do:

```
foreach(var g in top3peopleGroups)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Person Id: " + g.Key + ", Count: " + g.Count());
}
```

Comment: A little typo, actually it's OrderByDescending ;) Fixed

Comment: It will be a kind of top-list. Now I know the top-count but how can I determine who the person is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq

Comment: @Nime: it's in the `Key` property, check my edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the first part of the question. What list?

For the second part: The linq equivalent to `TOP` in SQL is `Take()`. Combine it with `Skip()` to get the next X lines of the results.