# List array duplicates with count

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array which contains the following results

```
red 
red
red
blue
blue
Green
White
Grey
```

and I want to get duplicate count of every value of array, for example:

```
red    Count=3
blue   Count=2
Green  Count=1
White  Count=1
Grey   Count=1
```

Comment: The similar  question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq

Comment: Is this site turning into "I have a homework, send me the code" thing?

Comment: @Frederik Mörk are you sure the op did not mean `"   red", " red   ", "         \t\tred"` as his/her strings? (I assume you deleted those white-spaces). I know that you can just Trim those, but Im not sure the op knows too.

Comment: @e-MEE Apparently not, because "red    Count=3"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

LINQ makes this easy:

```
Dictionary<string, int> counts = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                                      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                                    g => g.Count());
```

Comment: LINQ has conquered the World.

Comment: In one line of code you've just obliterated everyone else's answer :)

Comment: In addition would it be possible to get the duplicate indexes as well? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @desaivv: It would be possible, via a call to `Select` to start with which would provide `(value, index)` pairs. It wouldn't look pretty though.

Comment: This is a nice solution. Is there anyway do use this same method if the string is an object and you want to group by multiple fields of the object ?

Comment: @blueprintChris: Well you can use `GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Age })` instead... if that's not enough for what you want, please ask a new question.

Comment: I've tried that but the IDE complains about returning an anonymous type... I would ask a new question but my work blocks me from doing so... Any suggestions?

Comment: @blueprintChris: Wait until you get home to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Add them to a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(string s in list) 
{
   int prevCount;
   if (!counts.TryGet(s, out prevCount))
   {
      prevCount.Add(s, 1);
   }
   else
   {   
       counts[s] = prevCount++;
   }
}
```

Then counts contains the strings as keys, and their occurence as values.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm That is a very hard task, but Captain Algorithm will help you! He is telling us that there are many ways to do this. One of them he give me and I give it to you:

```
Dictionary <object, int> tmp = new Dictionary <object, int> ();

foreach (Object obj in YourArray)
  if (!tmp.ContainsKey(obj))
    tmp.Add (obj, 1);
 else tmp[obj] ++;

tmp.Values;//Contains counts of elements
```

Answer (score 1):

a little error above,
right code is:

```
string[] arr = { "red", "red", "blue", "green", "Black", "blue", "red" };

var results = from str in arr
              let c = arr.Count( m => str.Contains(m.Trim()))
              select str + " count=" + c;

foreach(string str in results.Distinct())
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

make another array of counts ....and loop on the original array putting a condition that if it found red increment the 1st cell of the count array ...if it found blue increment the second cell in the count array ....etc. 
Good Luck .

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
foreach (string s in inputStringArray)
{
    if (!ht.Contains(s))
    {
        ht.Add(s, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ht[s] = (int)ht[s] + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do the trick

```
    string[] arr = { "red", "red", "blue", "green", "Black", "blue", "red" };

    var results = from str in arr
                  let c = arr.Count( m => str.Contains(m.Trim()))
                  select str + " count=" + str;

    foreach(string str in results.Distinct())
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output:

```
red count=3
blue count=2
green count=1
Black count=1
```

Comment: -1: convoluted, and I see no reason to hurt performance by concatenate strings in the intermediate step.