# Equal values in array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I check if there are two or more equal values in one array?

eg. in this example, i want the program to tell me that there is a pair of 2 and a pair of 4

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 4, 2, 4 };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Count Duplicates in List with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq) or [C# list array duplicates with count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832602/c-sharp-list-array-duplicates-with-count).

Comment: By "check" do you mean you will accept a true/false answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Linq

```
var result = array1.GroupBy(i=>i)
                .Select(g=>new {Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
                .Where(x=>x.Count>1)
                .ToList();

foreach (var pair in result)
{
     Console.WriteLine("PAIR: " + pair.Value + " COUNT: " + pair.Count);
}
```

Comment: @SerialDownvoter Will you explain why?

Comment: @IV4 Your answer seems correct to me...

Comment: Nice answer I4V! Just a note, the `ToList` can be removed and it will still work.

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT] Sorry, this answers the question *"How can I check if there are two or more equal values in one array?"*, but it doesn't tell you the actual duplicates...

---

This would work, but possibly it isn't the most efficient way!

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

if (array1.Distinct().Count() < array1.Length)
    Console.WriteLine("Contains Dupes");
```

If you want the *most efficient* approach:

```
bool containsDupes(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        int n = array[i];

        for (int j = i+1; j < array.Length; ++j)
            if (array[j] == n)
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I don't think you can get much more efficient than that. It will return as soon as it finds any match.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it!

Comment: _eg. in this example, i want the program to tell me that there is a pair of 2 and a pair of 4_

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom Ah I see what you mean - I didn't notice that at first (might have been added later). I was answering the "How can I check if there are two or more equal values in one array?" of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Linq Statement like:

```
            var query =
                from numbers in array1
                group numbers by numbers into duplicates
                where duplicates.Count() > 1
                select new { Item = duplicates.Key, ItemCount = duplicates.Count() };
```

This will return the following:

```
Item 2: ItemCount 2
Item 4: ItemCount 2
```

Or another syntax for the same:

```
var query = array1.GroupBy(x => x)
                  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(x => new { x, Count = x.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ's `GroupBy`

Example:

```
var grouped = array1.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });

foreach(var item in grouped) {
    if (item.Count == 1)
        continue;

    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} instances of the number {1} in the array.", item.Count, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this syntax:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

var isThereAnyRepeated = (from i in array1
                            group i by i into g
                            where g.Count() > 1
                            select g).Any();

Console.WriteLine(isThereAnyRepeated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight variation of I4V's answer.

Instead of `Select` and `ToList` this uses `ToDictionary`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow_2013_05_27_EqualValuesInArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 1, 2, 4, 2, 4 };

            var tbl = array
                .GroupBy(n => n)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

            foreach (var pair in tbl)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is in array {1} times", pair.Key, pair.Value);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class item
{
    int value;
    int number;
}
list<item> items = new list <item>();


for(int i=0; i<array1.length;i++)
{
    if (i=0)
    items.add(new item(array1[i],1))

    else if (array1.contains(array[i])) items.add(new item(array1[i],))
    else items.add(new item(array1[i],1))

}
```