# Check if value is repeated in gridview

Tags: c#, .net

what would be a logic to check if input repeated in gridView?.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ7Yv.png]

Comment: Handle the `CellValueChanged` event of DataGridView and check for cell content duplicates?

Comment: Why is this getting voted up? It shows no research effort whatsoever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Find duplicate Values in Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279723/c-sharp-find-duplicate-values-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 2):

```
 private bool DuplicateExist()
        {
            var existingValues = dataGridView1.Rows
                                  .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                  .Where(x => x.Cells["Bar Code"].Value != null)
                                  .Select(x => x.Cells["Bar Code"].Value.ToString())
            return (existingValues.Count != existingValues.Distinct().Count())
        }
```

will this help you ?

Comment: You don't need `ToList()`.

Comment: yes thank you @pitersmx

Comment: Now, you can call this method in `CellValueChanged` event handler to check the duplicated every time user changes cell input value.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it like this in one query:

```
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("254");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("124");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("543");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("234");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("254");

        bool anyDuplicated = dataGridView1.Rows
            .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Where(x => x.Cells["Column1"].Value != null)
            .Select(x => x.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString())
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key)
            .Any();
```