# Count repeating values of the 1st column in a dataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, count

I have to add Full Name and its respective Count to a datagridview. I am setting the Full Name prior to the code below. There are multiple names repeating in the “Full Name” column.

[image]

To prevent that, I implemented something like this:

```
 bool found = false;
 int nameCount =0;
    if (dataGridView2 != null)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == fullName)
            {
                found = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {

            this.dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new object[] { fullName, nameCount });
        }
    }
```

This code basically eliminated individual names from repeating multiple times in the dataGridView and added only once.

[image]

What I need in my final result is something like the following. I tried incrementing nameCount in several places but I am not getting the right result.

[image]

Comment: If this data is coming from a database, the query can do this for you.

Comment: Not from a database. I have to do it manually.

Comment: Please show the code that's not working. Seems like you could just increment the count if `found == true`, something like: `else row.Cells[1].Value = row.Cells[1].Value + 1;`

Comment: It might be better, though, if you stored these as a list of custom classes and then bound your datagrid view to the list. Then you can just update items in the list and see the values in the grid.

Comment: @RufusL the code is working, the only part I can't seem to figure out is what I can do in order to get the count right.

Comment: If you [GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) the source by the `Full Name` Column/Property, you have the name in the key and also the count of the elements in each grouping. Where's the data coming from?

Comment: Also, you adding new rows to the DataGridView where the rows you're iterating come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `nameCount = 1` and increment the `Count` if `found == true`

```
        bool found = false;
        int nameCount = 1;
        if (dataGridView1 != null)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == fullName)
                {
                    found = true;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value) + 1;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { fullName, nameCount });
            }
        }
```

[image]

if you want to do this with another solution try this

```
var list = dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .Select(x => x.Cells["FullName"].Value);

        var q = from x in list
                group x by x into g
                let count = g.Count()
                orderby count descending
                select new { FullName = g.Key, Count = count };

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.FullName, item.Count });
        }
```

For more information, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601026/4977870) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454621/4977870)