# counting numbers in array above a certain level with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, comparison, numbers

I have an array of numbers:

```
int[] array = new int[]{ 18, 5, 10, 12, 15, 18 };
```

how do I count all numbers above a certain level (without repetitions)? will LINQ be any help?

For example - there are **3** numbers above 10 (18,and 15, 12).

there's only **1** number above 15 (**18,18 are practically the same number**).

**edit:** (sorry forgot about this one)

is it possible to count repetitions above a certain level?

i.e. in my example with "15" there will be 2 repetitions

**edit 2**

my way of "grouping"

```
int count1 = array.Where(x => x > 15).Distinct().Count();
int count2 = array.Where( x => x > 15).Count();
int count3 = count2 - count1;
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "practically in this statement "18,18 are practically the same number"?

Comment: they are at the same level, hence we will count them as 1 number..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int count = array.Where(x => x > 15).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: very good!! is it possible to count repetitions above a certain level?

i.e. in my example with "15" there will be 2 repetitions

Comment: you will have to use group by for that

Answer (score 2):

Further for counting numbers in group:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 66, 44, 1 };

            var x = array.GroupBy(t => t).Where(g => g.Key > 10).Select(g=>
                                                                          new {
                                                                              Number = g.Key,
                                                                              Count = g.Count()
                                                                            });

          foreach (var n in x)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Number{0}\nCounts:{1}", n.Number, n.Count);
          }
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I coulldn't find a way to make work Grouping, so I did this: int count1 = array.Where(x => x > 15).Distinct().Count();  int count2 = array.Where( x => x > 15).Count(); int count3 = count2 - count1; but thank you for your solution too

Answer (score 0):

Counting minus duplicates (outputs 4):

```
int[] array = new int[] { 18, 5, 10, 12, 15, 18 };
int count = array.Where(i => i > 10).Distinct().Count();
```

Counting duplicates (outputs 2: 18 & 18)

```
int duplicateCount = array.Where(w => w > 10).GroupBy(g => g).Where(w => w.Count() > 1).SelectMany(s => s).Count();
```

Or your cool solution of:

```
int count1 = array.Where(x => x > 10).Distinct().Count();
int count2 = array.Where(x => x > 10).Count();
int count3 = count2 - count1;
```

References:
[Remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array)
[Remove duplicates from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752/remove-duplicates-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp)
[how to find and print the duplicates values in array in c#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/csharplanguage/thread/69287fa5-c877-40fb-8c04-78ad91d82021)
[How to Count Duplicates in List with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq)

Comment: nice! Although I haven't noticed any performance difference between two methods (duplicate count) - I'll use your method because it's 1-line-long ;)