# How to count duplicate in linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Count Duplicates in List with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq)

Any idea how do you count a duplicate in linq. Let's say i have a list of Student objects
where i wanna find the amount of student called 'John'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var students = new List<string>{"John", "Mary", "John"};

foreach (var student in students.GroupBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", student.Key, student.Count());
}
```

Returns:

```
John: 2
Mary: 1
```

You can show the ones that have duplicates too:

```
var dups = students.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                   .Select(g => g.Key);

foreach (var student in dups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate: {0}", student);
}
```

Returns:

```
Duplicate: John
```

**Note:** You will need to change `GroupBy(x => x)` depending on what your `Student` object is of course. In this case, it's just a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var students = new List<string> { "John", "Mary", "John" };
var duplicates = students.GroupBy(x => x)
                         .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```