# Is there a way to count the index values of duplicate numbers in a binary search?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to count multiple entries in an already sorted array. In previous attempts, I've tried to use a list like this.

```
public static List<int> duplicate = new List<int>();
```

However, it wouldn't count properly and kept printing the same index number. I'm pretty much stumped on what to do at this point any help would be appreciated.

```
class binarysearch
{
    public static int lowestIndex = 0;
    public static int highestIndex;
    public static int middleIndex = 0;
    public static int indexValue = -1;

    public static int binarySearch(double[] data, double target)
    {
        int highestIndex = data.Length - 1;

        while (lowestIndex < highestIndex)
        {
            middleIndex = lowestIndex + (highestIndex - lowestIndex) / 2;
            if (data[middleIndex] == target)
            {
                indexValue = middleIndex;
                highestIndex = middleIndex;
            }
            else if (data[middleIndex] > target)
            {
                highestIndex = middleIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                lowestIndex = middleIndex + 1;
            }   
        }

        return indexValue;
    }
}
```

edit

```
public static List<int> duplicate = new List<int>();
```

is declared earlier in the code in

```
class dataset
{
   public static List<int> duplicate = new List<int>();
}
```

then printed later in the main method

```
foreach (object dupes in dataset.duplicate)
{
 Console.WriteLine(dupes);
}
```

Comment: What is `public static List duplicate = new List();`? It's not legal code unless you've defined your own `List` type. And how does it compute anything? Do you need to read [ask]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq

You can refer the above 1. All you need is tweak the code a bit to get the indexes of the duplicate numbers.

Comment: @Enigmativity i've amended the question to clarify

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can check the next value if it equals to the previous one.

Comment: @Enigmativity because it wasn't formatted as code, the `<int>` was swallowed as an unknown html tag

Comment: Warning: using static values for those indexes will lead to problems: 1) using this twice doesn't reset them (easily fixed); 2) multithreaded use will clash (and for instance a webapp is multithreaded)

Comment: I know, its static for testing purposes right now it would be changed in the final build of course

Comment: @user1672994 - How can you traverse an array in `O(1)`? It's `O(n)` by definition.

Comment: @thunderheck - What does the`List<int> duplicate` have to do with the `binarysearch` class? That is operating on a `double[]`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `O(n)`.