# How to distinct and count the duplicates inside a listbox?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a listbox where i can add items to it using datagridview, the thing is i want to determine which item is duplicate and how many times it duplicate.

- item1
- item1
- item2
- item2
- item2

> output  item1=2, item2=3

---

Here is the one that i tried which shows the last item that have been duplicate

```
int count = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
 {
  var s = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
  if (s.StartsWith(listfood))
   {
    if (s == listfood)
     {
      ++count;
     }             
   }
 }
MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var duplicateItems = listBox1.Items.GroupBy(x => x.ToString())
            .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
            .Select(x => new { Value = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Crap, you beat me by 2 mins. I was testing mine. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

var duplicates = listBox1.Items.GroupBy(x => x)
                               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                               .Select(y => new { ItemName = y.Key, Occurrences = y.Count() })
                               .ToList();

foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
    MessageBox.Show($"{duplicate.ItemName}: {duplicate.Occurrences}");
```

This solution uses [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/index) to query the `listBox1`'s `Items` collection and filter out any data we don't care about.

First, we use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) to sort the items. Then, [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) will filter out any items in the collection that only exist once. [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) allows us to "project" the items remaining in the filtered collection into a "new form" (we use an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) with an `ItemName` and `Occurrences` property to track the names of the duplicates and the number of times it appears in the collection).

Finally, [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2) converts the collection from an `IEnumerable<string> to a`List`type.`ToList`is optional depending on how you plan on using`duplicates`. In fact, my example doesn't need to call`ToList`because a`foreach`loop can iterate over an`IEnumerable` collection.

Comment: I can't understand how to make this work I'm pretty new to c# and i'm using this to output on a Form in visual studio. Can you explain how your code works?

Comment: @krljde Sorry, I quickly wrote that and had it write the output to the Console. I edited my answer so now it does a message box like your original example. I'll also add a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I know the Answers above will definitely work, but i can't understand it and make it work. This one works for me, where i transfer values of listbox to an array and check the duplicates inside that array.

```
     var list = new List<string>();
            foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                list.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            var r = from b in list
                    group b by b into g
                    let count = g.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count };
            foreach(var x in q)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("value: " + b.Value + " Count:" + b.Count);
            }
```

[Found my answer here](http://%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454601/how-to-count-duplicates-in-list-with-linq)

Comment: Linq Query Expressions is used in this answer, where as Linq Fluent Expressions is used in the other answers. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other). you could still avoid using the list variable and the for loop by simply changing the code to var r = from b in listBox1.Items.Select(x => x.ToString())